# Drag & Drop in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for assistance with implementing drag-and-drop functionality, including an extra condition for dropping items onto specific locations. While I've made progress, I believe there's room for improvement. Any guidance you can offer would be greatly appreciated as I work towards completing this screen. Thank you in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCiAI.jpg)

**logic**

```
 const [animatedValue] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 }));

  const handleDrop = (payload, gestureState) => {
    
    console.log('Drop event triggered with payload:', payload, gestureState);
    
    // Update the animated position on drop
   if (gestureState) {
      const { moveX, moveY } = gestureState;
      // Update the animated position on drop
      Animated.spring(animatedValue, {
        toValue: { x:-19, y: -210.53425 },
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }
  };
  const [animatedValue2] = useState(new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 }));
  const handleDrop2 = (payload, gestureState) => {
    
    console.log('Drop event triggered with payload:', payload, gestureState);
    
    // Update the animated position on drop
   if (gestureState) {
      const { moveX, moveY } = gestureState;
      // Update the animated position on drop
      Animated.spring(animatedValue2, {
        toValue: { x:-170, y: -270.53425 },
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }
  };
```

**Drop Location**

```
<View style={{width:'46%', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#000', height:80, padding:5, marginBottom:5}}>
                            <Text style={{fontFamily:'Cheesecake', fontSize:14, color:'#000', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:14,}}>Cat</Text>
                            {/* <Image source={require('../../assets/image/cat2.png')}  style={{alignSelf:'center'}}/> */}
                            
                                <DraxView
                                  style={{height:60,}}
                                  payloadTarget={['cat']}
                                  onReceiveDragDrop={({ dragged: { payload }, ...gestureState }) => handleDrop(payload, gestureState)}
                                >
                                  
                                </DraxView>
                              
                          </View>
                          <View style={{width:'46%', borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#000', height:80, padding:5, marginBottom:5}}>
                            <Text style={{fontFamily:'Cheesecake', fontSize:14, color:'#000', textAlign:'center', width:'100%', letterSpacing:1, lineHeight:14,}}>Fan</Text>
                            
                                <DraxView
                                  style={{height:60,}}
                                  payloadTarget={['fan']}
                                  onReceiveDragDrop={({ dragged: { payload }, ...gestureState }) => handleDrop2(payload, gestureState)}
                                >
                                  
                                </DraxView>
                              
                          </View>
```

**Draggable Items**

```
 <View style={{width:'23%', alignContent:'center', alignItems:'center',  height:55, padding:5, marginBottom:5}}>
                              
                                <DraxView onDragStart={() => console.log('Cat drag started')}  payload="cat"  style={{position: 'absolute',
                transform: [{ translateX: animatedValue.x }, { translateY: animatedValue.y }]}} >
                                 
                                    <Image source={require('../../assets/image/cat2.png')}  />
                                 
                                  </DraxView>
                              
                            </View>
                            <View style={{width:'23%', alignContent:'center', alignItems:'center',  height:55, padding:5, marginBottom:5}}>
                              
                                  <DraxView onDragStart={() => console.log('Bat drag started')}  payload="bat" style={{position: 'absolute',
                transform: [{ translateX: animatedValue4.x }, { translateY: animatedValue4.y }]}}> 
                                    <Image source={require('../../assets/image/bat.png')}  />
                                  </DraxView>
                              
                            </View>
```